# Python: Reading CSV in results in ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to create a dataframe of the following very simple .csv

```
Content, Art, Version, Number, Question, Date, Performance, N1, Pall, Nall
somecontent, someart, 1.10.117, 081 01 04 02 01, 64936, 19.05.2018, 0.682427191039005, 8, 0.294000000, 29
```

As you can see, the different columns match (10 columns with 10 matching values in the row).

I have this csv saved as "bla.csv" (yeah someone is at a creative high) and do the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv('bla.csv')
```

This results in

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Why?

Comment: I ran your code in jupyter notebook, it is working for me. maybe in your `bla.csv` file has mistaken characters

Comment: your code works. did you `import pandas as pd` yet? if it doesn't work, try to give a full path of your csv file and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: this is super weird... I did import pandas. I will try the full path item. Interestingly enough, I can read it into a dataframe and save it to another file. It throws an error, but it still exports the data correctly.

Comment: Ok so I have taken the lines of code out of the file in which I am running it and removed all other packages that I load. Now it works. I am superconfused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to replicate your problem it works perfectly fine at my computer. It could be that the separator gives an error. You can specify the separator by `df=pd.read_csv('bla.csv', sep=',')`. Depending on the way the csv-file is generated it could for example also be a semicolon.